# Video streaming solutions

Tags: unity-game-engine, silverlight-5.0, gstreamer

I am attempting to stream a video, in a format unity3d can access, like an mjpg. I have gone through several possible solutions, including gstreamer(only does client side as far as I could tell by the examples), yawcam(I couldn't find a way to access the image directly), and silverlight(due to simply not being able to find how the heck webcam streaming was doable) I am currently just looking for any more methods of getting video over from one side to the other. Could I possibly simply read the images into a byte array and send it over a socket? Maybe I missed something in the previous three possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to stream video from a server than you can use Ogg encoding + [WWW.movie](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW-movie.html) to map it to a texture. Assuming you have a Pro license, as I think this is a Pro only feature. If this is a local file, either bundled with the app or in external folder, we use the brilliant [AVPro Windows Media](http://www.renderheads.com/portfolio/UnityAVProWindowsMedia/) or [AVPro QuickTime](http://www.renderheads.com/portfolio/UnityAVProQuickTime/). MJPEG does offers super smooth scrubbing with AVPro but generates enormous files. Definitely not ideal for streaming or even download!

Finally RenderHead also has a [Live Camera capture plugin](http://www.renderheads.com/portfolio/UnityAVProLiveCamera/) that could meet your needs.